# Compare character with multiple characters in C

Tags: c, if-statement, character, logical-operators

How can i compare a character in C with other characters without using an 'if'
with tons of '||'?
For example let's say I have a character named 'i' that I want to compare with 8 other characters that have no connection between them whatsoever, and if 'i' equals to at least one of those 8 characters then the expression is true.
Something like this:

```
if(i == c1 || i == c2 || i == c2 ........){ /* do stuff */}
```

But on a big application these comparisons are a lot, not just 3 or 8.
Is there a smart and fast way to achieve something like this and not end up with ugly looking code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: if *i* is variable please remove those ''. Also what is c1?

Comment: You can store c1,c2,,,,,,,cn variables in an array. Then compare by a loop.

Comment: Use `switch` statement.

Comment: all variables are characters @giorgi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `'c1'`, ... are just a single `char` constants, you can use:

```
if ( strchr("12345", ch) != NULL )
    ...
```

("12345" are `c1`, `c2`, ...)

`strchr()` will, however, also match the implcit trailing NUL terminator (`'\0'`). If that is a problem, you can compare this value explicitly. As the input string is searched from start, you might want to have the more propable values at the beginning.

Note that `strchr` does return a pointer to the matching char; just if you need that.

If you can group the values, e.g. "letters", "digits", etc., have a look at [ctype.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/).

If the values are variables, you can either copy them into an array of `char` before the compare (**do not forget about the  trminator!**) or hold them in the array anyway: `array[0]` is `c1`, ... .

If all this is not possible, you are likely busted with `strcpy`. You could use this:

```
// assuming there are always the same variables used.
static const char * const ca[] = { &c1, &c2, ... };

char val;

for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < sizeof(ca) / sizeof(ca[0]) ; i++ ) {
    if ( *ca[i] == val ) {
        // match!
    }
}
```

You could pack that into a function with some decoration here and there.

Comment: Can I use something like {c1, c2, c3, '\0'} in place of "12345"?

Comment: You can use any string constant. Check for _compound literals_. or enter the values as octal or hex-codes: `\x20`. Ehm... are the values variables actually? Your question did state different.

Comment: Yes all values are variables, that's why it's hard to do it without avoiding having a mess of a code. Also their names are bigger not just 'c1' or 'i'.

Comment: @AnnoyingQuestions: Please edit your question `'c1'` is a character literal actually (assumint `c1` is a single character). However, I updated my answer

Comment: You can also introduce him to `if (strchr ("12345", ch))` itself and prompt a bit of thought and learning `:p`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: What do you mean?

Comment: Just without the `!= NULL` to have them focus for a moment on the `strchr` return and various ways of integrating it with the test.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: That is the way I actually write it myself (I only use bool/adjective functions without explicit compare actually), so it was kind of "automatic". However, I do not see much sense in changing this right now. The OP seems to have understood the point.